# Deleting Signature After CreateItemTemplate

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using the below code that I found for a new template but I want to delete the signature.

I either need code to delete the signature after the below code or a completely new code that opens a new email, clears body then inserts template.

```
Sub NewTemplate()
Set objMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("S:\filepath.oft")
Set newItem = Nothing
With objMsg
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@email.com"
    .Display
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objDoc = objMsg.GetInspector.WordEditor
If objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailAutoSig") Then
   set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
   objBkm.Select
   objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
End If
```