# Set signature, in preview pane, based on from address

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following code from [Trigger Outlook Event: Change Signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42723453/trigger-outlook-event-change-signature:) (credit to [Chazjn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1596582/chazjn)):

```vb
Dim WithEvents myInspector As Outlook.Inspectors
Dim WithEvents myMailItem As Outlook.MailItem

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Set myInspector = Application.Inspectors

End Sub

Private Sub myInspector_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
        
    If TypeOf Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then
        Set myMailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem
    End If
        
End Sub

Private Sub myMailItem_PropertyChange(ByVal Name As String)
On Error GoTo ErrorCatcher

    Dim signatureName As String
    Dim signatureFilePath As String
    
    ' Properties we are interested in: "SendUsingAccount" / "SentOnBehalfOfName"
    ' Both get fired when the 'From' field is changed/re-selected
    ' So we are only going to trigger on one event or we will call the code twice
    
    If Name = "SentOnBehalfOfName" Then

        ' Delete the current signature
        Call DeleteSignature(myMailItem)

        ' Insert the new signature at the current cursor point
        ' The cursor will be at the point where the old signature was deleted
        signatureName = GetSignatureName(myMailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName)
        
        signatureFilePath = GetSignatureFilePath(signatureName)
        Call InsertSignature(myMailItem, signatureFilePath)

    End If

    Exit Sub

ErrorCatcher:

    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub

Private Function DeleteSignature(objMail As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim objBkm As Word.Bookmark

    Set objDoc = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    If objDoc.Bookmarks.Exists("_MailAutoSig") Then
        Set objBkm = objDoc.Bookmarks("_MailAutoSig")
        objBkm.Select
        objDoc.Windows(1).Selection.Delete
    End If

End Function

Private Function GetSignatureName(sender As String)

    Select Case sender

        Case "Sales"
            GetSignatureName = "Sales"

        Case Else
            GetSignatureName = "default"

    End Select


End Function

Private Function GetSignatureFilePath(signatureName As String) As String

    GetSignatureFilePath = Environ("AppData") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & signatureName & ".htm"

End Function

Private Function InsertSignature(objMail As MailItem, signatureFilePath As String)

    Dim objDoc As Word.Document
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngEnd As Range

    Set objDoc = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor

    Set rngStart = objDoc.Application.Selection.Range
    rngStart.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Set rngEnd = rngStart.Duplicate
    rngEnd.InsertParagraph

    rngStart.InsertFile signatureFilePath, , , , False
    rngEnd.Characters.Last.Delete

    objDoc.Bookmarks.Add "_MailAutoSig", rngEnd

End Function
```

It changes the signature based on the email address I select in the "from" list.

It works when I hit "New Email" but when I hit "reply" the code won't work unless I hit the "pop out" button.

Why is this and what can I do to make the code work when replying without having to pop out the message?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make sure your code runs as soon as the `Inspector` is shown instead of running only when the `SentOnBehalfOfName` property changes. Try to call you `myMailItem_PropertyChange` method from `myInspector_NewInspector`.

Comment: Hmm... I apologize in advance, i have experience with vba in access and excel but brand new to automating outlook so I'm not really sure what's going on. When exactly is the inspector shown? I tried calling the myMailItem_PropertyChange method from myInspector_NewInspector and nothing happened. I even put a msgbox to show me the current value of myMailItem but the code isn't being triggered. It appears to me that a message that isn't a pop out isn't considered an inspector. Would this be considered a namespace or activewindow or session?

Comment: Yes, Inspector is the standalone Outlook window that shows a particular message (as opposed to an Explorer). Have you tried to remove your error handler and step through the code?

Answer (score 0):

You want to process the [InlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.inlineresponse) rather than the Inspector.

Sample code to demonstrate the use of the event from [Send As a Delegate or a Distribution Group by default](https://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/setfromaddress.htm)

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents myOlExp As Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set myOlExp = ActiveExplorer
End Sub

'Applies to Outlook 2013/2016/2019/365 Reading Pane Reply
Private Sub myOlExp_InlineResponse(ByVal objItem As Object)
    SetFromAddress objItem
End Sub

Public Sub SetFromAddress(oMail As mailItem)
    ' Set your preferred default From address below.
    ' Exchange permissions determine if it is actually stamped
    ' as "Sent On Behalf Of" or "Sent As".
    ' The address is not properly updated for the InlineResponse
    ' feature in Outlook 2013/2016/365. This is only a visual bug.
    oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "delegate@domain.com"
End Sub
```